# Swift - Cambiar el tamaño de un UIVIew

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tengo un UIView el cual le doy un height de 100 al inicio

`viewPedido = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 20, width: scView.frame.width - 60, height: 100))`

pero despues voy agregando al UIView contenido, el problema es que el contenido es dinamico por lo cual desde el principio no se cuanto va a ser, entonces voy calculando el tamaño del contenido para al final cambiar el tamaño del UIView el problema es que al cambiarlo no se me refleja el cambio en la vista, pero si lo cambia por que mas abajo tengo otra vista que observa cual es el tamaño del UIView anterior para posicionarse y si cambia su posición. Este es el codigo con el que cambio el tamaño

`viewPedido!.frame = CGRect(x: viewPedido!.frame.minX, y: viewPedido!.frame.minY, width: 10, height: 400)`

Comment: usa constraint en lugar de frame, y para manejar un tamaño variable seria mas fácil usar un stacview en lugar de un view.

Comment: Cambias el tamaño en `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`?